# How to exclude a local package for transitive dependency in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, dependency-management

In an Android mobile app, I am including a package in `/app/libs` named `3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release.aar`

I got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class okhttp3.Address found in modules 3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release-runtime.jar (3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release.aar) and okhttp-3.12.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.Authenticator found in modules 3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release-runtime.jar (3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release.aar) and okhttp-3.12.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1)
```

and 222 lines of similar errors, all related to 2 packages.

I am trying to exclude them in `app/build.gradle` with

```
dependencies {
    implementation "3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release.aar" {
      exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
      exclude group:'com.squareup.okio', module:'okio'
    }
  }
```

However it doesn't work as it is a local package, not a library.

So I am getting this error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method 3ds-sdk-2.3.4.0-production-release.aar() for arguments [build_eaobhegdrynooj4ngteg4v2o3$_run_closure2$_closure17@69e8efd7] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

How to exclude a local package?

Answer (score 0):

Add this build gradle

```
android {
configurations{
 all*.exclude module: 'okhttp'
 }
}
```

Comment: Would not this exclude it from everywhere? I want to avoid duplicate, not suppress the package completely